# Sort response getting from server in alphabetic order

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am getting response like this from server,

```
[  
 {  
  "id":"b2",
  "type":"ball"
 },
 {  
  "id":"a1",
  "type":"apple",
 },
 {  
  "id":"d4",
  "type":"dog",
 },
 {  
  "id":"c3",
  "type":"cat",
 }
]
```

but I need to sort the above response data based on alphabets wise, based on "type". And then display the list, I am using model to parse the data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data structure are you parsing the JSON into? If, for example, you have an `Item` class similar to:

```
class Item {
  Item(String id, String type) { ... }
  String getType() { ... }
  String getId() { ... }
}
```

And you parse that JSON into some kind of `List<Item>`, then the following should work for sorting by type (API level 24+), see [Comparator.comparing](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function%3C?%20super%20T,%20?%20extends%20U%3E)):

```
List<Item> items = ...; // however you parse the JSON
Comparator<Item> byType = Comparator.comparing(Item::getType);
Collection.sort(items, byType); // items will now be sorted
```

For a more general approach that will work with older API levels, you can define the `byType` comparator like this:

```
Comparator<Item> byType = new Comparator<Item> {
 public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
   return a.getType().compareTo(b.getType());
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make your class Comparable and use :

```
type.compareTo()
```

In your own compareTo method in oder to be able to sort them by type?

Answer (score 0):

Json is an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.
See http://json.org. 
Convert to Object to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an Object and implement `Comparable<>` Interface. The use:

```
CompareTo()
```